# Arduino cannot sync

Tags: arduino-mega

I have seen many of these problems and followed all the instructions i can find, i made sure the com was the correct one, i made sure th e drivers were installed. I cannot upload my sketch...anyone else have any ideas, ive been working on this forever trying to figure it out...

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-objcopy" -O ihex -j .eeprom --set-section-flags=.eeprom=alloc,load
--no-change-warnings --change-section-lma .eeprom=0  "C:\Users\reneg\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_1951/HelloWorld.ino.elf" "C:\Users\reneg\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_1951/HelloWorld.ino.eep" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-objcopy" -O ihex -R .eeprom  "C:\Users\reneg\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_1951/HelloWorld.ino.elf" "C:\Users\reneg\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_1951/HelloWorld.ino.hex" Multiple libraries were found for "LiquidCrystal.h"  Used: C:\Users\reneg\Documents\Arduino\libraries\LiquidCrystal  Not used: C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\LiquidCrystal Using library LiquidCrystal at version 1.0.5 in folder: C:\Users\reneg\Documents\Arduino\libraries\LiquidCrystal  Sketch uses 1900 bytes (5%) of program storage space. Maximum is 32256 bytes. Global variables use 59 bytes (2%) of dynamic memory, leaving 1989 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2048 bytes. C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avrdude -CC:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/etc/avrdude.conf -v -patmega328p
-carduino -PCOM1 -b115200 -D -Uflash:w:C:\Users\reneg\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_1951/HelloWorld.ino.hex:i


avrdude: Version 6.3, compiled on Jan 17 2017 at 12:00:53
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/etc/avrdude.conf"

         Using Port                    : COM1
         Using Programmer              : arduino
         Overriding Baud Rate          : 115200 avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x24 avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x24 avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 3 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x24 avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 4 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x24 avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 5 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x24 avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 6 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x24 avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 7 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x24 avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 8 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x24 avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 9 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x24 avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x24

avrdude done.  Thank you.

Problem uploading to board.  See http://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Troubleshooting#upload for suggestions.
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok figured it out.......had to change the board type/////